# AWS S3 using powershell - Credentials issue

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

I created ps script trying to send files to S3 bucket.
I specified a profile name called Reports and basic script look like this:

```
# Config
Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName GoReports
$bucket_name = 'aws.bucketName'

# Data preparation stage
# ...

# Send to AWS S3
Write-S3Object -BucketName $bucket_name -File "c:\backup\sales.gz" -Key "/group1/shop1/sales.gz"
Remove-Item "c:\backup\sales.gz" -Include *.gz
```

I use TaskScheduler on windows to launch this task. Every step has its own status logged.
Now when I look into my eventlog I see that sometimes all the files are sent correctly but sometimes it gives me a shout:

> No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults

What can be the reason?
Task is set to be launched with highest privileges.

Comment: What version of AWS Tools module are you using?

Comment: The error is not preventing the success of your use case, at least that is what I take from your post. If that is correct, then, unless the message stops/impacts your success, it probably a false negative and can be safely ignored. Especially if it is not consistent as well.

Comment: @AndrewRyanDavis:aws --version gives
aws-cli/1.16.303 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.13.39